# Android WebViewClient url redirection (Android URL loading system)

Tags: android, redirect, webview, webviewclient, android-webview

I was trying intercept webview request using: `ShouldInterceptRequest`, inside it I used `HttpUrlConnection` to fetch data from server, I set it to follow the redirection, which is transparent to webviewclient. This means when I return WebResponseResource("", "", data_inputstream), webview maynot know the target host was changed. How can I tell the webview this happened?

```
ourBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                String url) {
                    ..... //some code omitted here

                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                try {
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) newUrl.openConnection();
                    conn.setFollowRedirects(true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                   ..... //

                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    is = conn.getInputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, is);

            }
        }
```

If I request "google.com", it should be redirected to "google.co.uk", but webview didnt know the redirection, if the link of css file attaching with "co.uk" is  "/render/something.css", the webview still go to "http://www.google.com/render/something.css" to find the css file which should be "http://www.google.co.uk/render/something.css".

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Certain metadata (url, headers, etc..) can't be specified by the `WebResourceResponse` class. That means that you can only use `shouldInterceptRequest` to supply different data (change the page's content) but you can't use it to change the URL it's being loaded at.

In your case you're consuming the redirect within the `HttpUrlConnection`, so the WebView is still thinking that it's loading "http://www.google.com/" (even if the content is coming from "http://google.co.uk/"). If Google's home page doesn't explicitly set a base URL the WebView will continue to assume the base URL is "http://www.google.com/" (since it hasn't seen the redirect). Since relative resource references (like `<link href="//render/something.css" />`) are resolved against the baseURL (which in this case is "http://www.google.com/" and not "http://www.google.co.uk/") you get the result you observed.

What you could do is use `HttpUrlConnection` to figure out whether the URL you're going to load is a redirect and return `null` in that case. However I would strongly advise against using `HttpUrlConnection` from `shouldInterceptRequest` in general - the WebView's network stack is much more efficient and will perform fetches in parallel (whereas using `shouldInterceptRequest` will serialize all of the loads in pre-KK WebViews).

Answer (score 0):

Close the HttpClient `setFollowRedirects(false)` and Make webiew reload the redirected URL.

Fake code:

```
if(response.code == 302){
  webview.load(response.head("location"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can enable HTTP redirects globally for all the HttpURLConnection objects:

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
```

then in the *shouldInterceptRequest()* method you check for the connection response code:

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
  ...
  int respCode = conn.getResponseCode();
  if( respCode >= 300 && respCode < 400 ) {
    // redirect
    return null;
  } else if( respCode >= 200 && respCode < 300 ) {
    // normal processing
    ...
}
```

The Android framework should call *shouldInterceptRequest()* again with the new URL which is the redirection target, and this time the connection response code will be 2xx.

Comment: You need to disable the "followRedirects" instead of enabling (they are enabled by default). You'll never receive 3xx code when followRedirects is enabled.