# Android WebView custom headers

Tags: java, android, webview, header

I am currently using this code to add a custom header to android `WebView`

```
Map<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
extraHeaders.put("example", "header");
webView.loadUrl(url, extraHeader);
```

Above code is working but only on the main page. So if I write this code `echo $_SERVER['example']` it prints `header`. But there is an `iframe` in the loaded URL which shows an undefined error when I try the same code. Is there any way I can fix this?

So what I want to do is add custom header not only to the main loaded URL but also on the `iframe` of the loaded page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom headers to WebView resource requests - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610790/add-custom-headers-to-webview-resource-requests-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible with Android WebView itself. You have to work around either in your page code, or in your app's code, or on the server.

For fixing this on the page's side, you can use `XMLHttpRequest` for loading subresources. But for that you will have basically to construct the page on the fly.

On the app's side, you can use `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest`, to intercept all the network requests. You are not allowed to just modify the provided request, instead, you will need to make a new request yourself, but there you will be able to set any headers you want. See this example: [Android WebViewClient url redirection (Android URL loading system)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237451/android-webviewclient-url-redirection-android-url-loading-system)

On the server side, you can look into `Referer` header of subresources, which must contain the url of the page that has requested it.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(token));
```

in MyWebViewClient

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    try {
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url.trim())
                .addHeader("token", mToken) //add headers
                .build();
        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        return new WebResourceResponse(
                getMimeType(url), // set content-type
                response.header("content-encoding", "utf-8"),
                response.body().byteStream()
        );
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

//get mime type by url
public String getMimeType(String url) {
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        if (extension.equals("js")) {
            return "text/javascript";
        }
        else if (extension.equals("woff")) {
            return "application/font-woff";
        }
        else if (extension.equals("woff2")) {
            return "application/font-woff2";
        }
        else if (extension.equals("ttf")) {
            return "application/x-font-ttf";
        }
        else if (extension.equals("eot")) {
            return "application/vnd.ms-fontobject";
        }
        else if (extension.equals("svg")) {
            return "image/svg+xml";
        }
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put this setting to your web setting, every request from webview will be using this `User-Agent` header.

`webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("user-agent-string");`

Comment: where exactly would you add this?

Comment: it only works to set the user agent not custom headers!

Comment: yes, this code just for set your user agent header not custom header, you can put in `onCreate`

Comment: This saved me.  Just couldn't get my token to add properly in Xamarin and this allowed a secured workaround!

Answer (score -1):

Just add this piece of code before load URL:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
}
```

Comment: how removing cookies is related to adding headers?